# Round bars in matplotlib histogram

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I use `matplotlib.pyplot.hist()` for a histogram plot in python. If I use a visible edgewidth, for example when using `histtype='step'`, the upper corners of the single bars are slightly round. I want them to be sharply rectangular instead. I already tried using the `solid_capstyle` keyword, which works for influencing the shape of line plots, but this doesn't work in `hist()`. Any ideas on how to do that? Thanks!

Here's my minimal self-contained example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

mu = 200
sigma = 25
x = mu + sigma*np.random.randn(10000)

fig, (ax0, ax1) = plt.subplots(ncols=2, figsize=(8, 4))
ax0.hist(x, 20, normed=1, histtype='step', facecolor='g', alpha=0.75, linewidth=4.)
ax0.set_title('step')
# Create a histogram by providing the bin edges (unequally spaced).
bins = [100, 150, 180, 195, 205, 220, 250, 300]
ax1.hist(x, bins, normed=1, histtype='step', rwidth=0.8, linewidth=4.)
ax1.set_title('unequal bins')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('test.png', dpi=200)
```

Comment: Do you see this [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/histogram_demo_histtypes.html) with `histtype='step'` as round or sharp?

Comment: Please provide a (minimal) amount of code to reproduce yous problem.

Comment: Yes I see that in the example. In the minimal code above I exaggerated the line width so that the effect becomes more obvious. Any ideas?

Comment: @frixhax why would you even want to increase your linewidth (I can see you have done here for purpose)? If you have the default linewidth, one can still clearly see your histogram and can understand the distribution of your data.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The capability to control this property is available in MatPlotLib 1.4. So, I recommend upgrading; for example if you use pip:

```
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

Then use the `joinstyle` keyword argument (`['miter' | 'round' | 'bevel']`) in your calls to `hist`; e.g.:

```
ax0.hist(x, 20, normed=1, histtype='step',
         facecolor='g', alpha=0.75, linewidth=4.,
         joinstyle='miter')
```

Note that `'miter'` (square corners) appears to be the default in MPL 1.4, so specifying this parameter is not actually necessary in your case. I've included it here to be explicit.

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it seems to default to that now.